# MySQL Compare TIME data with Current Time

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL Column `time_start` with data type `TIME` , `00:00:00` Format

I tried to get row in the next 60 Minutes

```
SELECT * FROM time_table
        WHERE time_status = 'OK' AND (time_start > TIME(NOW()) AND time_start < TIME(NOW()) + '60 MINUTE')
```

But apparently it doesnt work

Then i tried using CURTIME

```
SELECT * FROM time_table
    WHERE time_status = 'Waiting' AND (time_start > CURTIME() AND time_start < (CURTIME() + '60 MINUTE'))
```

it still doesn't work

Is there anything wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to increase a datetime value by using a string won't work. You have to use the `INTERVAL` keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM time_table
        WHERE time_status = 'OK' AND
       (time_start > TIME(NOW()) AND time_start < TIME(NOW()) + INTERVAL 60 MINUTE)
```